# My public static void main(String[] args){ (Windows 8) gets an error

Tags: java, eclipse

Yes, I admit, I AM watching a tutorial for my game. Yet he can run it perfectly. I just have one issue. This is my main, and then I'll show you my problem. Or maybe by the title you can find it in my main. Oh, those pasted code lines are also part of my main.

```
package game.Mixit.Game.main;

public class main {
    import java.awt.Canvas;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public static final int WIDTH = 160;
            public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH/ 12*9;
            public static final int SCALE = 3;
            public static final String name = "Game";

            private static Object start;

            private JFrame frame;

            public boolean running = false;

            public Game() {
                setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
                setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
                setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));

                frame = new JFrame(NAME);

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                frame.add(this.BorderLayoud.CENTER);
                frame.pack();

                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);


                public synchronized void start() {
                  running = true
                  new Thread(this).start();

                }

                public synchronized void stop() {
                  running = false
                }

            }

        public void run() {
          while (running) {
              System.out.println("Hello World");}
          }



        public static void main(String[] args){
            new Game().start();
        }



        public void start() {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post what error you are getting. There is also nothing wrong with following a tutorial :)

Comment: Before going to swing, you should really go through the basics of Java. You have serious syntax errors. You have methods declared within methods/constructors.

Comment: You most likely want `new Game().start();` to be `new Game().run();`

Comment: What is this tutorial?  It seems bizarre to have a structure that could require you to type `game.Mixit.Game.main.main.Game`.

Comment: @pickypg, I disagree. It looks like OP is trying to do threads.

Comment: Post your error.  Without the error message we're only guessing.

Comment: @DavidKnipe He is trying to do threads, but `Game` implements `Runnable` and not `Thread`.

Comment: @DavidKnipe I missed the empty `start()` method at the bottom. Though this would be a good reason that this does _nothing_ rather than being the compilation error that I originally expected.

Comment: @pickypg Either way would work, I suppose. rainkinz has done it your way. I was thinking `new Thread(new Game()).start();`.

Comment: @DavidKnipe That's probably what it's supposed to be, but it shouldn't generate an error as-is (just doing nothing), so it's impossible to say.

Comment: No, it wouldn't have made an error, but OP was being unhelpful and didn't actually tell us whether they had an error. Now let's all move on to other questions where we actually have enough information to go on :-)

Answer (score 1):

You've got your main method defined in a non static inner class, so the JVM cannot access it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a class defined inside a class here that looks odd and you have a number of syntax errors that your IDE should be yelling at you about. You probably want something like this:

```
package game.mixit;                // <= Lowercased package

// added a few imports
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

// Removed the main class 

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable { 

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static final int WIDTH = 160;
  public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
  public static final int SCALE = 3;
  public static final String NAME = "Game";

  private static Object start;

  private JFrame frame;

  public boolean running = false;

  public Game() {
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

    frame = new JFrame(NAME);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.pack();

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public synchronized void start() {
    // fixed some missing ;
    running = true;
  }


  public synchronized void stop() {
    running = false;
    System.out.println("Stopping");
  }

  public void run() {
    start();
    while (running) {
      System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Game game = new Game();
    new Thread(game).start();

    // Just for kicks wait a bit then 'stop' the game
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    game.stop();

    System.out.println("Stopped");
  }
}
```